# Converting .py to .exe generates black window application and disappears after a few seconds

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, pyinstaller

I'm trying to convert my pygame project to one .exe file, but the output is black window (image 3).

I've tried to do that using auto-py-to-exe application with settings like this (image 1). Before that I've tried with this line of code in PowerShell.

```
PS D:\my_projects\python_projects\tic_tac_toe_project> pyinstaller --onefile -w tic_tac_toe.py
```

Both solutions return same output (image 2 and image 3) without error messages while expected output is (image 4).

**Image 1**

[image: image1]

**Image 2**

[image: image2]

**Image 3**

[image: image3]

**Image 4**

[image: image4]

[console_output_img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhCOq.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Edit:

So this is a problem with using `pygame.font.SysFont()`. I am not sure why it will not work, and its tough to find out, as it uses a .pyd file, which is an extension for a c API i believe. The work around for this is to use `pygame.font.Font()` instead. In your app you send `None` as the font, which just returns the default font for pygame which is freesansbold.ttf. To use this font you need to include it in the package, as it does not exist in the windows registry.

```py
import os # Importing os and pygame at top of spec sheet
import pygame

pygame_dir = os.path.dirname(pygame.__file__) #  Grabbing the name of the local pg install
path_t_font = os.path.join(pygame_dir, 'freesansbold.ttf')

a = Analysis(['tic_tac_toe.py'],
             pathex=[],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[(path_t_font, '.')], #  Adding the font to data
             .....
```

Then you need to change line 12 in your `user_interface.py` to:

```py
# self.font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 24) Instead of this use the code below
self.font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 24)
```

Not sure why this happens, but this is a hacky fix.

If you are going to use `--onefile` mode you also need to add this to the top of your tic_tac_toe.py script.

```py
import sys, os
os.chdir(sys._MEIPASS)
```

---

### From old anwer:

Add the verbose flag to your PyInstaller spec sheet to get an idea of what is happening. First create your spec sheet using `pyi-makespec <YOUR SCRIPT>` and then open the spec sheet it creates.

Go down to the `exe=EXE` section and add this bit of code.

```py
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          [('v', None, 'OPTION')],  # Add this right here
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='main',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True )
```

Now bundle your package using the custom spec sheet, and run it. You should get a console that will display some messages. This will tell you what is being loaded and give you an idea of what is happening.

Comment: I haven't found any errors in console window. It still disappears after a few seconds but all files are imported. So I still don't know what's wrong?

Comment: Do you have any dependencies at all? Icons, images, files?

Comment: No, it's just multiple .py files project.

Comment: I've just made test file which has all classes inside, the only imports are 'sys', 'pygame', 'pygame.font'. When I tried to make .exe the result was the same. No errors, black app window.

Comment: Mistyped the last comment. From the run bar (windowskey-r) type ```cmd /k "the complete path to your exe" ```. This will keep the console open so you can see errors. Make sure console = true in your spec sheet.

Comment: Make sure an actual cmd console is popping up not just the blank tic tac toe app

Comment: Still the same output.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the console at runtime without closing the app?

Comment: Added at the end of question.

Comment: It looks like its having trouble with numpy. Try explicitly importing numpy in your run script. If that doesnt work try adding numpy under hidden imports in the spec sheet

Comment: The problem with numpy is:
  File "site-packages\numpy\random\__init__.py", line 180, in <module>
  File "mtrand.pyx", line 1, in init numpy.random.mtrand
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.random.common'
[3856] Failed to execute script tic_tac_toe

Comment: If you have a place to host your files, I could take a look at them when I have some time if you'd like.

Comment: Appreciate it, here's a link : https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1uKDGZrJNJ9wksluVzuoqEeQ8AgrLAJGO?usp=sharing

Comment: I found the solution, you were right; no errors. What a pita lol.

Comment: Thank You so much! Now I can focus on gameplay bugs. I'm very grateful for Your help!